# form:select returning a comma separated list

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Someone guided me towards the spring MVC form tld yesterday morning and I've been struggling to do what looks like a very simple task ever since!  It looks like a simple solution but I just can't seem to get it right.  I'm thinking I must be misunderstanding something very fundamental to be unable to get it working. I was wondering if someone could point out where I'm going wrong?

At the moment all I'm trying to do is display a list of values in a jsp select.
The model entity is very simple (and I realise needs a little fine tuning)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id  private String userId; 
private String userName;
private String passwordCode;
private Date dateOfBirth;

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public String get PasswordCode () {
    return passwordCode;
}

public Date getDateofBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}
}
```

My controller is also currently very simple

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController  extends JFrame { 

@Autowired private MeetingDAO meetingDAO;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String HomePage(Model model) {

        List<User> userlist = userDAO.ListAll();
        model.addAttribute("userlist ", userlist);
        model.addAttribute("User", new User());

        return "Home";
    }
```

I got this far by using another q/a on stack overflow and I wonder if this is where my misunderstanding originates.  I am passing in the list of values as an attribute as I have all along.  I got a lot of errors doing this until I realised that I also needed to 'pass' the User model so that the spring tags in the jsp would understand the structure of the User object.  This means I am now passing 2 attributes - User, as I understand it just so the form understands the structure (although maybe if I was cleverer this would also return the selected object?) and the userlist which is the actual data.

In the jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<body>

    <h2>Users List Page</h2>

    <form:form action="/home" method="Post" modelAttribute="User" >
        <form:select path="userName">
            <form:options items="${userlist}"/>
        </form:select>

        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="View"/>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have paired this back down for simplicity but have tried quite a few things (itemvalue, itemlabel amongst others).  This code returns all the data but in a comma separated list of all values (id, name, password, date).  Whatever I try to do with path, itemvalue etc it won't just display one field.  Ideally I wold like to display - userName (userId) - but at this stage I would probably settle for userName!

From my flapping about my impression is not connecting that User is an item in the userlist.  If I feel I'm getting close it complains that userId (etc) is not a method of type array (which I assume means it is looking at the list) or if it seems to have understood the properties it has no data (which I guess means it's not picking up the list!).

could anyone help !?

Just to add this is the closest I think I have got but it complains that User is not valid a property of User ?

```
<form:form action="home" method="Post" modelAttribute="User" >
    <form:select path="User" >
        <form:options items="${userlist}" itemValue="userId"  itemLabel="userName" />

    </form:select>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="View"/>
 </form:form>
```

Comment: i am sorry.. but what is it exactly that you are looking for? (I am assuming.. you added `userlist` attribute to the model.. and when you are retrieving it.. you are getting comma separated values of elements in in `userlist`.. but you want to set them as options of select?)

Comment: Yes I would like to use elements of the user in the select list.  So for example rather than seeing "userId1, Bob Hoskins, pwdcode, 12/01/2015 00:00:00" (etc) I would at a minimum Just see "Bob Hoskins" and ideally be able to set it to "Bob Hoskins (UserId: userid1)".  I thought I should be able to do this by setting the form:select path or form:options itemLabel attributes ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form:form action="home" method="Post" modelAttribute="User" >
<form:select path="userId" >
    <form:options items="${userlist}" itemValue="userId"  itemLabel="userName" />
</form:select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="View"/>
```

This code will have the selected userId set in User object which you will get when you post the form.

path variable should be bound to backing object property here backing object is User so you should bind its userId property.

Comment: can you specify which object you are adding as model attribute ? I suppose it is User Object which you have specified in your question(code).

Comment: When I do this I get the error "Invalid property 'userId' of bean class [[Ljava.lang.Object;]:".  This seems a it odd to me as if I put path="User" it does at least realise it should be looking at a User object and errors with  Invalid property 'User' of bean class [com.org.model.Meeting] ? (apologies I got distracted and was too slow to edit.)

Comment: Many thanks to all that helped. Actually although this was very useful it also made me realise I've been looking in the wrong place for 1 - 2 days! As I was filling the UserList from a stored proc not directly from hibernate it wasn't actually a list of Meeting objects after all but a list of comma separated values. Apologies I didn't post this bit of code (or look at it again until now). Ouch!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for setting options (assuming `userlist` is a list of `User` objects and has fields `userId` and `userName`):

```
<c:forEach var="u" items="${userlist}">            
    <form:option item="${u}" itemValue="${u.userId}"  itemLabel="$(u.userName}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Do you mean reverse out of form tags altogether.  This is along the lines of what I was doing before but I was hoping to get the spring thing going ?! <select id="userlist">
    <c:forEach var="u" items="${userlist}" >
       <option value="${u}" >${u[1]} (ID: ${u[0]})</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all that helped.  Actually although this was very useful it also made me realise I've been looking in the wrong place for 1 - 2 days!  As I was filling the UserList from a stored proc not directly from hibernate it wasn't actually a list of Meeting objects after all but a list of comma separated values.   Apologies I didn't post this bit of code (or look at it again until now). Ouch!